# Remove the last number in data frame columns depends on their data frames - optimizing the code

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, dictionary

I wrote the code as follows to remove the last number in data frame columns depends on their data frame.  is there a better way of implementing it instead of using a lot of **if** ?

I want to remove all the columns name that are ended to 1 in data frame 1 and all the columns name that is ended in 2 in data frame 2 and respectively for all data frames.

```
def remove(df):
    for key, val in df.items():
        
        if key == "df3":
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'(?:0)$', '', regex=True)
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'_$', '', regex=True)

        if key == "df5":
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'(?:1)$', '', regex=True)
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'_$', '', regex=True)
            
        if key == "df4":
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'(?:2)$', '', regex=True)
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'_$', '', regex=True)
            
        if key == "df6":
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'(?:3)$', '', regex=True)
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(r'_$', '', regex=True)
            
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dict to specify which values should be deleted to save some if conditions. I also combined the removal of the digit with the removal of the underscore which might not be what you wanted but I can only guess due to the lack of real data and the expected output :

```
def remove(df):
    m = {
        "df3": "_0$",
        "df5": "_1$",
        "df4": "_2$",
        "df6": "_3$"
    }
    for key, val in df.items():
        
        if key in m:
            val.columns = val.columns.str.replace(m[key], '', regex=True)       
    return df
```